# SHA256 hash bruteforcer

Tags: performance, rust, cryptography

I made a SHA256 hash bruteforcer as my first program in Rust. It's very specific to what I'm trying to bruteforce and I'll probably never find it.

I translated it from Python to make it faster, but can I make it even faster than this?

```
// Disable snake case warning
#![allow(non_snake_case)]

extern crate crypto;
extern crate rand;

use self::crypto::digest::Digest;
use self::crypto::sha2::Sha256;
use std::{i64, fs, process};
use std::time::Instant;
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
   // Local variables
   let listWin = ["black","green","orange","orange","orange","black","black","orange","black","black","black","orange","black","black","orange","orange","green","black","orange","black","black","orange","orange","black","black","black","orange","black","black","orange","orange","orange","orange","black","orange","black","black","orange","orange","black","black","orange","green","black","orange","orange","orange","orange","green","black"];
   let public_seed = "2132110516";
   let round_ = 4645230;

   let now = Instant::now();
   let mut nbOfTry: u32 = 0;
   let mut roundVerif = 0;
   let mut predict;

   loop {
      let randomSeed = &CreateSeed(32);
      predict = PredictColor(randomSeed, public_seed, round_);  

      // Check if the hash is correct by predicting the first 50 round of the day
      while predict == listWin[roundVerif] {
         roundVerif += 1;
         predict = PredictColor(randomSeed, public_seed, round_ + roundVerif as u32); 

         if roundVerif > 45 {
            fs::write("seed.txt", randomSeed).expect("Unable to write file");
            process::exit(1);
         }
      }
      roundVerif = 0;

      nbOfTry += 1;
      if nbOfTry % 1000000 == 0 {
         println!("{}", nbOfTry);
         println!("In {} secondes", now.elapsed().as_secs());
      }
   }
}

//---------------------------------------------------
// CreateSeed()
//---------------------------------------------------
// Description : Creates a random seed 
//
// Input      : Number of byte
// Output     : Random seed with a len of 2*nbByte
//---------------------------------------------------
fn CreateSeed(nbByte: u8) -> (String){
   let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
   let mut seed = String::new();
   let mut byte: String;

   for _x in 0..nbByte {
      let rand = rng.gen::<u8>();
      byte = format!("{:x}", rand);   

      if rand <= 15 {byte = format!("0{}", byte);}
      seed = format!("{}{}", seed, byte);
   }
   return seed;
}


//---------------------------------------------------
// PredictColor()
//---------------------------------------------------
// Description : Predict the roll 
//
// Input      : server_seed : serveur seed
//              public_seed : public seed
//              round_      : First round of the day
// Output     : --
//---------------------------------------------------
fn PredictColor(server_seed: &str, public_seed: &str, round_: u32) -> (String){
   let toHash;
   let mut hasher = Sha256::new();

   // Hash everything
   toHash = format!("{}-{}-{}",server_seed, public_seed, round_ );
   hasher.input_str(&toHash[..]);
   let hash_ = hasher.result_str();

   // Get the roll number from the hash
   let decNumber = i64::from_str_radix(&hash_[..8], 16);
   let roll = decNumber.unwrap() % 15;

   // Print the color
   if roll == 0 {return "green".to_owned();}
   else if roll >= 1 && roll <= 7 {return "orange".to_owned();}
   else if roll >= 8 && roll <= 14 {return "black".to_owned();}
   else{return "failed".to_owned();}
}
```

Comment: Why did you decide to disable warnings? Idioms exist for a reason.

Comment: See the [tag info](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/rust/info) for sample steps you can take to improve your code already.

Comment: How fast is your current code? How fast is the Python version? How are you running your code? Are you using release mode? Have you performed any profiling? How sure do you feel that your algorithm is a good choice?

Comment: FWIW, I disagree with the close votes. The code *appears* to be complete and not pseudocode or similar.

Comment: It would be good to include the exact versions of the crates you are using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run and address feedback from automated tools to get easy feedback without having to make use of another human's time. Possible tools include:

- The Rust compiler. Don't turn off warnings.
- [Rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt) is a tool for automatically formatting Rust code to the community-accepted style.
- [Clippy](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rust-clippy) is a tool for finding common mistakes that may not be compilation errors but are unlikely to be what the programmer intended.

These detect things like:

- incorrect / inconsistent indentation.
- unneeded usages of `return`
- non-idiomatic Rust naming

Your variables have useless prefixes and suffixes. Don't blindly use Hungarian notation in a strongly typed language (e.g. `nb`). Dnt ndlssly abbv vrbs (don't needlessly abbreviate variables).

With this initial clearing of the underbrush, we can start to look at the code.

- Don't use `extern crate` in modern Rust ([What's the difference between use and extern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29403920/155423)).
- Don't use `self::cratename`, just use `cratename`.
- I prefer to group all imports from the same crate into a single use statement.
- Declare your variables as *close as possible* to where they are defined. Declare them inside of loops, especially if they aren't used outside of the loop or are reset inside the loop.
- Use an infinite range instead of manually incrementing a variable.
- Your function documentation is mostly useless. It's not using a doc comment (`///`). It repeats things like the function name. ([How do you document function arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30009650/155423))
- The type `(String)` has an unneeded parenthesis.
- Your number formatting is grossly inefficient. You allocate many strings when you only need to extend an existing one. ([What is the easiest way to pad a string with 0 to the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50458144/155423); [How can I append a formatted string to an existing String?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28333612/155423))
- Don't use `_x` if the variable is never used. Just use `_`.
- Don't use magical values like "failed". Make use of Rust's `Result` type ([What's the benefit of using a Result?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22187926/155423))
- There's no need to slice the string with `[..]`. Most of the time, a reference to a `String` will suffice ([How does a reference to a String become a string slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49315047/155423))
- There's no need to return an owned `String`; a `&'static str` will suffice ([What are the differences between Rust's `String` and `str`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24158114/155423))
- Avoid using `as` to convert numbers. Prefer `From::from` instead ([How do I convert between numeric types safely and idiomatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28273169/155423))
- It's inefficient to convert the digest result to a string, slice the string, then convert back to a number. Perform the operations directly on the digest buffer. ([How can I convert a buffer of a slice of bytes (&[u8]) to an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29307474/155423); [How to get a slice as an array in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25428920/155423))
- Don't use an `i64` when you mean to use an `u32`
- Using a `match` is cleaner than multiple `if`/`else` statements.

```
use crypto::{digest::Digest, sha2::Sha256};
use rand::Rng;
use std::{convert::TryInto, fs, process, time::Instant};

fn main() {
    // Local variables
    let winners = [
        "black", "green", "orange", "orange", "orange", "black", "black", "orange", "black",
        "black", "black", "orange", "black", "black", "orange", "orange", "green", "black",
        "orange", "black", "black", "orange", "orange", "black", "black", "black", "orange",
        "black", "black", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "black", "orange", "black",
        "black", "orange", "orange", "black", "black", "orange", "green", "black", "orange",
        "orange", "orange", "orange", "green", "black",
    ];
    let public_seed = "2132110516";
    let round = 4_645_230;

    let now = Instant::now();

    for tries in 0.. {
        let random_seed = &create_seed(32);
        let mut predict = predict_color(random_seed, public_seed, round).unwrap();
        let mut round_verifications = 0u8;

        // Check if the hash is correct by predicting the first 50 round of the day
        while predict == winners[usize::from(round_verifications)] {
            round_verifications += 1;
            predict = predict_color(random_seed, public_seed, round + u32::from(round_verifications))
                .unwrap();

            if round_verifications > 45 {
                fs::write("seed.txt", random_seed).expect("Unable to write file");
                process::exit(1);
            }
        }

        if tries % 1_000_000 == 0 {
            println!("{}", tries);
            println!("In {} seconds", now.elapsed().as_secs());

            if tries == 5000000 { return }
        }
    }
}

/// Creates a random seed with a length of `2 * bytes`
fn create_seed(bytes: usize) -> String {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut seed = String::with_capacity(2 * bytes);

    for _ in 0..bytes {
        use std::fmt::Write;
        write!(&mut seed, "{:02x}", rng.gen::<u8>()).unwrap();
    }
    seed
}

/// Predict the roll
fn predict_color(
    server_seed: &str,
    public_seed: &str,
    first_round_of_the_day: u32,
) -> Result<&'static str, ()> {
    let mut hasher = Sha256::new();

    // Hash everything
    let to_hash = format!("{}-{}-{}", server_seed, public_seed, first_round_of_the_day);
    hasher.input_str(&to_hash);

    let mut hash = [0; 32];
    hasher.result(&mut hash);

    let leading_bytes: &[u8; 4] = hash[..4].try_into().unwrap();
    let number = u32::from_be_bytes(*leading_bytes);

    match number % 15 {
        0 => Ok("green"),
        1..=7 => Ok("orange"),
        8..=14 => Ok("black"),
        _ => Err(()),
    }
}
```

Running this in release mode:

```
% time ./target/release/review
0
In 0 seconds
1000000
In 2 seconds
2000000
In 4 seconds
3000000
In 7 seconds
4000000
In 9 seconds
5000000
In 11 seconds

real    12.078  12077581us
user    11.879  11879005us
sys 0.033   33467us
cpu 98%
mem 968 KiB
```

Compared to your original:

```
% time ./target/release/review
1000000
In 14 secondes
2000000
In 28 secondes
3000000
In 42 secondes
4000000
In 56 secondes
5000000
In 70 secondes

real    1:10.49 70485131us
user    1:10.16 70162635us
sys 0.137   136869us
cpu 99%
mem 980 KiB
```

The improved version takes **17%** of your original time (a 5.8x speed increase).

---

Using a random number generator for the seed is probably a bad idea. It's totally reasonable for a RNG to repeat a value, but that won't change your results. You might as well start at 0 and work your way up. This also makes it trivial to stop and resume.

The problem appears to be embarrassingly parallel, so that would also be an avenue to investigate.

Comment: Thanks for your really nice answer, I'll have a lot of things to read with all the link you sent. 


For my function documentation, it's what my school wants me to do, so that's what I'm used to. It's when I'll write librairies in C, the documentation will have to be very clear for the user. 




I originaly thought of working my way up, but the seed changes everyday, which makes it nearly impossible to crack. 


The seed looks like that  : `"a3bbba746fa85f6305ee3873b6d267d9872eceb6c6174e33075d73a5259b4cb6"`

Comment: the maximum value is then : "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"
In decimal : 2^(64*4) = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936

I think my calculs are correct. I guess randomly guessing might be better because I won't do half that number in a day.


I tried running your code, it looks like you're using 98% of your CPU. When I run it, it uses a maximum of 9% of my cpu. How can I make it run full speed ?

Sorry for the bad formating, it's the first time I'm using this site.

Comment: Randomly guessing will never be better though. The RNG might return zero 100 times in a row, computing the same (failed) value again. There's no information you can make use about being "close" that might make jumping around the search space have a benefit. Jumping around randomly won't make you faster (in fact, it's probably slower).

Comment: The 98% number reported by my shell is of a single core, I believe. Your number might be out of your total CPU; do you have an 8-, 10- or 12-core processor by any chance?

Comment: I have a AMD Ryzen 5 2600. 6 Cores, 12 Logical processors

Comment: In that case you are likely getting ~100% of 1/12 => ~8.3%. That ties into the "parallelize it" comment.